# iOS 4.3.1 on the phone - does it work with XCode 3.x ? or only 4.0.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I upgraded my iPhone to the latest OS (4.3.1) yesterday, and noticed there is no corresponding XCode 3.x release, only a 4.x release (4.0.1).

Since upgrading I am getting warnings when I try to install apps on the device using my development certificates (Application failed codesign verification).

Not sure if the OS upgrade on the Phone and the error message are related, so I'm just asking the question if anyone else had this happening?

And are we supposed to use XCode 4.0.1 when we develop for the 4.3.1 iOS release or can we use a 3.x version as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xcode version number isn't important, but the SDK version number is. You can get the latest SDK with either Xcode 3.2.6 or Xcode 4.0.1 at the time that I'm writing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can still download the XCode 3.2.6, it goes with the SDK 4.3, and it is free to download.

You can try with XCode 4 as well, but you have to either to have an iPhone or Mac Developer account (99$/year) or you need to buy it from the AppStore

Answer (score 0):

It still works, however of you first attach your iPhone to Xcode it will ask you to download the debugging symbols off the phone. Answer Yes to this question and you are ready to go.

However there is *one more thing*: usually Apple makes restrictions about the SDK you should use when submitting apps to the store. So if you want to submit an app it could be that you have to use the most recent SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an application directly from XCode 3.2.6 on a device where iOS 4.3.1 has just been installed won't work.

First, you need to open XCode's Organizer window and ask to collect information from the device. Then it will work fine.